# Suggest Prototype/jQuery Widgets

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, javascript

I am revamping a website that (now) uses Prototype framework. In the process of revamping, I realized that the site was using about 7-8 JavaScript widgets from various sources. I am removing all JavaScript widgets and replacing them with Prototype based counterparts. Can you suggest tried and tested widgets for following functions:

1. Popup Calendar (bound to a textbox)
2. Calendar (embedded in a div, scrollable by month, I need to color the cells via code)
3. Dropdown Menu (one level vertical drop down menu)
4. Slide Show (embedded in a div, with prev/next buttons)
5. Light Box (slide show but overlay style)
6. Modal Box (ok cancel button)
7. Scrolling Marquee (horizontal scroll marquee or ticker)
8. Tool Tip

If there is one (tried and tested) library that does it all, I'll be happy to use it.

### EDIT

I am open to using jQuery as an alternate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery UI contains some http://jqueryui.com/demos/. The other could be made with some lines of jQuery code.

Comment: I've chosen jQueryUI. I like the part where you say `The other could be made with some lines of jQuery code`. I just ended up doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I have had great results with these plugins:

1. jQuery UI
2. jQuery UI
3. superfish
4. fancybox
5. facebox

tooltip, marquee, etc i'd prefer to code myself.

Answer (score 1):

As for some **Prototype-based** alternatives:

For modal popups and carousels, check out: http://www.prototype-ui.com/

For calendar popups, I really liked: http://calendarview.org - you can embed this or pop it up.

A lot of other stuff such as drop-down menus I would code myself. Also keep an eye on [Scripty2](http://scripty2.com/)!

I don't think you will find a library that does it all. The JQuery UI stuff is good too, but like you I came from a Prototype background and I found the above solutions just fine for me.